# Populate by custom index in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

Is it possible to populate a field in MongoDB using a different index (not _id). This index is unique and populating by _id would not be useful at all for the context of my problem.

I'm talking about something like this:

```
pop_options: {
  path: 'cars',
  model: 'Car',
  index: 'Car.regnumber'
}

User.find({name: 'John'}).populate(pop_options).exec(function(err, user){
//Code
})
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Short answer? [No](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2562). It's not too difficult to do yourself, though, and mongoose turns it into separate queries anyways so it's not really a performance hit.

Comment: Side note, this sort of situation suggests your data is relational. Is there a reason you have to use mongodb in this scenario?

Comment: It's actually a kind of 'cache' for an extern API. So instead of calling the API everytime I want to get data for an object I'm trying to store them all in my local db (they're about 50).

Comment: Is the schema structured? You could still store it in a relational database, if you know the schema ahead of time. (Sorry, I know this is sort of outside the scope of the question).

Comment: Yes it is and I know it ahead of time. The problem is that I'd have to run a relational-db only for this since all the rest of my project works with mongodb right?